# 'addEventListener' para habilitar autoplay en Chrome

Tags: javascript, html5

estoy desarrollando una página al estilo de "Elige tu propia aventura". El inicio consiste en una frase que se modifica en relación a una canción que suena de fondo. Todo anda bien en distintos navegadores a excepción de Chrome, que no permite el autoplay a menos que el usuario interactúe con la página, entonces pensé en iniciar con un pop-up de alerta con un texto introductorio que, al darle click, inicie la música. En el código se ve así:

```
const audio = document.getElementById('audio');
function inicio() {
  audio.play();
}
alert("texto introductorio").addEventListener("click", inicio());
```

Pero en la consola me aparece el siguiente error: behavior.js:11 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined
Cuál es el problema? Por otro lado, es la solución que se me ocurrió... si hay una mejor forma de resolverlo, agradezco cualquier sugerencia. Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Notas**
>
> ---
>
> El diálogo `alert` debe ser usado para mensajes que no requieren respuesta por parte del usuario, otra que la aceptación del
> mensaje.
>
> [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/alert)

> Buenas prácticas para desarrolladores web
>
> Elementos de audio/video
>
> Recuerda una cosa: Nunca asumas que el vídeo se va a reproducir, y no muestres
> un botón de pausa si el vídeo no se está reproduciendo. Es tan importante
> que lo escribiré de nuevo mas adelante por aquellos que pasan de largo del post.
> Debes de observar siempre la `promesa` devuelta por la función `play` para ver si esta fue `rechazada`.
>
> [Google developers](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes#audiovideo_elements)

Ya que los diálogos `alert` o `confirm` no nos dejan interactuar con la pagina no seguirá saltando el error.

Una mejor opción sería que se muestre un modal y en este se agregue el boton para reproducir el audio.

Utilicé `bootstrap` y `jquery` para este ejemplo

HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>DS20</title>

        <!-- Fonts -->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,600" rel="stylesheet">
        <!--- css de bootsrap --->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <audio src="/Platinum Level Circulation.mp3" type="audio/mp3" id="audio">
        </header>
    <!--- CDN de jquery --->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!--- cdn de js --->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!--- cdn del js de bootsrap --->
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="./js/app.js"></script>
    </body>
    <div id="play" class="modal">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
            <i class="fas fa-play"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
</html>
```

JavaScript

```js
const audio = document.getElementById('audio');
var promise = audio.play();

if (promise !== undefined) {
    promise.then(_ => {
    // Autoplay started!
    }).catch(error => {
    // Autoplay was prevented.
    // Se muestra el modal en la pantalla.
    $('#play').modal('show');
    // El evento hidden.bs.modal se ejecuta cuando se há terminado de esconder
    // el modal al darle click
    $('#play').on('hidden.bs.modal',function (){
        // Inicia la reproducción del audio
        audio.play();
    });
    });
}
```

Comment: Gracias, pero me dice en consola que falló el autoplay porque el usuario no interactuó con el documento...

Comment: voy a complementar mi respuesta con algo que encontré en una pagina de google

Comment: Ahí cambié el código pero sigue tirando el mismo error... 

Comment: ok, ya encontré una forma, en lugar de ejecutar un confirm o un alert, que aparezca un moda. voy a re editar mi la respuesta

Comment: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function

Comment: tienes que agregar los cdn de boostrap y jquery a tu archivo html, vuelvo a editar la respuesta

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111389/discussion-between-alejandro00-and-noob).

Answer (score 0):

Para reproducir el video cuando este listo y cargado en el navegador

```
video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', () => {
  video.play()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola como están? yo solucioné este error con este trozo de código:

```
        audio.src = song;
        urlsong = song;
        audio.load();
        setTimeout(function(){
            audio.play();
            }, 0);
```

La variable "song" es: "getAttribute('href')". quiere decir que es una URL. example: ./archivo_de_musica.mp3

Probado navegador: chrom
GitExample: sinuhemelis/reprductoraudioJs

Comment: La variable "song" es: "getAttribute('href')". quiere decir que es una URL. example: ./archivo_de_musica.mp3